# How to bind arrays by columns in R...?

Tags: arrays, r, binding

Looking for the smartest and shortest way to bind the following two arrays in R. Excepted output is also given...

```
#Creating two arrays
(a <- array(c(1:9,19:27), dim = c(3,3,2)))
(b <- array(c(10:18,28:36), dim = c(3,3,2)))

#Wanted array by binding a and b
(wanted <- array(1:36, dim = c(3,6,2)))
```

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `abind`

```
library(abind)
res <- abind(a, b, along = 2)
attr(res, "dimnames") <- NULL
identical(res, wanted)
#[1] TRUE
```